# Delete local bookmarks that haven't been touched in 7 days

Tags: mercurial, bookmarks

How should I clean up all the local bookmarks that hasn't been touched recently (say in the past 7 days)? Using

```
hg bookmark -d <bookmark name>
```

seems unscalable.

Comment: By "touched", do you mean "committed to" or "interacted with in any way (such as by updating to it)"?  The latter information may not exist.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no information as to when a bookmark was updated to last or when it was created; you can only obtain the information of the age of the commits they are attached to easily, e.g.

```
hg log -r "bookmark() and date('-1000')"
hg log -r "bookmark() and date('<01/30/2015')"
```

for all bookmarks attached to commits created in the last 1000 days or all bookmarks attached to commits older than January 30th 2015.

EDIT to add: There is the [Journal Extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/JournalExtension). It allows to actually track when and to which revisions a bookmark was attached to. Thus you might want to enable this extension if you want to solve your problem for the future.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to delete all the bookmarks find in the hg log?

Comment: Just delete the .hg/bookmarks file if you really just want to delete all bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

`hg bookmark -d` can take multiple arguments, so combining with the answer above you can do:

```
hg bookmark -d `hg log -r "bookmark() and date('-1000')" -T '{bookmarks} '`
```

I use this to remove all public bookmarks, since I only use them locally:

```
hg bookmark -d `hg log -r "bookmark() and public()" -T '{bookmarks} '`
```