# Remove all local bookmarks from Mercurial repo

Tags: awk, mercurial

`hg bookmarks --delete` can be used to remove a bookmark.

Is there any way I can remove all bookmarks in a Mercurial repo through some bash script? I think that this may be possible using awk - but it's a bit beyond me.

The format of the `hg bookmarks` output is (for example):

```
2018.02.706 Customer App 5255:c1321f7f3903
2018.02.707 Customer App 5255:c1321f7f3902
```

I need to get just:

```
2018.02.706 Customer App
2018.02.707 Customer App
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk 'sub($NF,"")' file

2018.02.706 Customer App 

2018.02.707 Customer App
```

Comment: For completeness, here's the script I used to remove the hg bookmarks (it also trims spaces both leading and ending):  

hg bookmarks | awk 'NF' | awk 'sub($NF,"")'  | awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' | awk  '{print "hg bookmarks --delete \x27" $0 "\x27"}' > clear-bookmarks.sh

Comment: @dubs I'd say, post that as a new answer, its more complete than the others.

Comment: That would fail if `$NF` contained RE metachars. Avoid using input data in regexps or replacement text unless necessary to perform some specific task that requires it. `$NF=""` or `sub(/[^[:space:]]+$/,"")` would do the same thing more robustly but those would still leave trailing blanks at the end of each line like your current solution does.

Answer (score 2):

This should remove last field:

```
awk 'NF{NF--}1' file
```

This just sets the last field to nothing:

```
awk '{$NF=""}1' file
```

Comment: or `awk 'NF--' file`

Comment: @Cyrus Can not be used,  Whit a empty line you get this message `awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=t FNR=4) fatal: NF set to negative value`.  That is why you should set last field to empty or test if NF is true `>0` and then subtract `1`

Comment: Yes, in that case that would be a problem. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: That first one (`NF--`) is relying on undefined behavior so what it does will vary between awk versions.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50084393/960558) (with some *possible* needed corrections) will be easier and more natural, than awk-ing: pure Mercurial, nothing more

Comment: Good suggestion.  However, it gets tricky with spaces in the name and also doesn't take into account that a change set can have multiple bookmarks against it which causes even more difficulty with parsing as the -T '{bookmarks}\n' will report (potentially) many bookmarks per line.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the assistance from in previous responses, here's the complete script I used to remove mercurial bookmarks:

```
hg bookmarks | awk 'NF' | awk 'sub($NF,"")' | awk '{print "hg bookmarks --delete \047" $0 "\047"}' > clear-bookmarks.sh
```

Use the following if you want to ensure that leading and trailing spaces are removed:

```
hg bookmarks | awk 'NF' | awk 'sub($NF,"")' | awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' | awk '{print "hg bookmarks --delete \047" $0 "\047"}' > clear-bookmarks.sh
```

---

My scripting experience isn't wonderful by any means - but it seems to do the job!

Comment: You don't need multiple pipes and calls to awk to do what those lines of code will do, they'll fail given some values of `$NF`, and you should use octal instead of hex to get the `'`s, see http://awk.freeshell.org/PrintASingleQuote.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm unsure how to reduce the number of pipes.  To me this is clear, but I would appreciate a suggested improvement to my version?

Comment: `awk 'NF' | awk 'sub($NF,"")' | awk '{ gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print }' | awk '{print "hg bookmarks --delete \047" $0 "\047"}'` is equivalent to just 1 awk command `awk 'NF && sub($NF,"") { gsub(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/, ""); print "hg bookmarks --delete \047" $0 "\047"}'` but that's still fragile,lengthy, and unnecessarily complicated. Just use one of the scripts I posted at https://stackoverflow.com/a/56906355/1745001.

Answer (score 1):

If you really just want to delete all bookmarks, just delete the `.hg/bookmarks` file from your repo's hidden `.hg` directory.

The bookmarks may come back if you pull them from a remote location, so you'd have to also do `hg book push -B 'your bookmark name'` to also remove the bookmark from the remote location, but this is a problem you would face with any other method for deleting bookmarks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the spaces in your input are blank chars as it appears in your sample input, to do what you asked for in your question portably and robustly is:

```
$ sed 's/ [^ ]*$//' file
2018.02.706 Customer App
2018.02.707 Customer App
```

and to get the output the command line in [your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56902098/1745001) would produce is:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*\) .*$/hg bookmarks --delete '\''\1'\''/' file
hg bookmarks --delete '2018.02.706 Customer App'
hg bookmarks --delete '2018.02.707 Customer App'
```

If you feel a burning desire to use awk then it'd be:

```
$ awk '{sub(/ [^ ]+$/,"")}1' file
2018.02.706 Customer App
2018.02.707 Customer App

$ awk '{sub(/ [^ ]+$/,""); print "hg bookmarks --delete \047" $0 "\047"}' file
hg bookmarks --delete '2018.02.706 Customer App'
hg bookmarks --delete '2018.02.707 Customer App'
```

Replace `/ [^ ]+$/` with `/[[:space:]]+[^[:space:]]+$/` if the white space in your example can be something other than a single blank char.